# C function to modify text file

Tags: c

```
int cripta(string nomef) {  
    FILE* file=fopen(nomef, "r+");  
    if (file==NULL)  
        return error;  
    char c;  
    long pos;  
    pos = ftell(file);  
    c=fgetc(file);  
    while (c!=EOF) {  
        fseek(file, -1, SEEK_CUR);  
        pos = ftell(file);  
        c++;  
        fputc(c, file);  
        pos = ftell(file);  
        c=fgetc(file);  
        pos = ftell(file);  
    }  
    fclose(file);  
    return done;  
}
```

This function modifies a file increasing of 1 any caracter. I tested it with a .txt file with only "abcde" in it. The result is a process that never ends, and a big file that starts with 'b', continues with a lot of 'c' and finishes with another 'b'. Debugging i found out that the problem is the "fgetc(file);" in the loop. In the second iteration it starts to get always 'b'. I use MinGW and CodeBlocks. I cant understand where is the error. Many thanks and sorry for the english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char c;  
long pos;  
pos = ftell(file);
c=fgetc(file);
while (c!=EOF) {
    fseek(file, pos, SEEK_SET);
    fputc(++c, file);
    fflush(file);
    pos = ftell(file);
    c=fgetc(file);  
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling fflush?

Comment: @doogabides  It to determine the write to the file.

Comment: Don't think it's necessary. IO is supposed to be buffered for performance. You'll be reading the next char so who cares if the one behind you is updated now or later.

Comment: @doogabides probably, this program isn't work properly if you do not `fflush`.

Comment: I dont know why fflush is necessary, but it solves the problem!

Comment: It is necessary to apply to the actual file(fflush) because file is buffered .

Comment: @doogabides see **7.19.5.3 The fopen function 6** of [n1256.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY reads automatically flush writes. No biggie, your code is clear and works. But you really only need  `while ((c=fgetc(file))!=EOF) {fseek(file, -1, SEEK_CUR);fputc(++c, file);}`

Comment: @doogabides `-1` is not guarantee return to where you want if in the text file. also I tried your code. but it does not work.

Comment: @doogabides Apparently you do not seem to read the link destination.

Answer (score -1):

use:

while ((c = fgetc(file )) != EOF) and do fputc to file2 not to same file!!

Comment: post to another file not to same read from a.txt and write to b.txt ,you can also read file in char buffer[] and do char[i] ++; to increase all characters from buffer with 1 and then write buffer[] to a text file ,you dnt need to read char by char

Comment: I'll try this, it seems to be helpful. Thank you.